# Select one group at one time in a dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have a dataframe.

I grouped the dataframe using following code.

```
  val w = Window.partitionBy($"column name").orderBy($"column name".asc)

  val group = table.withColumn("rank", row_number().over(w))
```

I want to know is there any way to take one group at a one time. Because I need to put another logic to each group.

Thank you :)

Comment: well what is the subsequent logic that you would like to do?

Comment: Question will be more clear if you can share what that logic will be. For now I can say that there are functions like `collect_list` using that you can make a list of values in a group and further use that list to implement your logic.

Comment: I want to add values row by row in a one column and each time after adding compare this value with another value which is in the same row but different column. Do till those two values get equal. When those values are same get that raw ID. I want to repeat that logic for every group.

Comment: When you say add one by one does that mean to just sum the values for a group and then compare to another value?

Comment: @big_mike_boiii Not sum the values for a group. First I want to take one group. After I get my first column's first row value. I compare it with first row value in my second column. Then I add first and second row values in my first column. Then I compare the total with second column second row value. Likewise I add first, second and third row values in my first column and compare total with third row value in second column. I want to do it till total and second column row value get equal. I'm really sorry if my previous comment is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did to solve my issue :)

First I partition the dataframe according to a column name and write each partition to a csv file and save it in a new folder.

```
    df
    .write
    .partitionBy("column name")
    .csv("path_to_save_csv_file")
```

Second I collect csv file's names in above folder to a list.

```
      val dir = new File("path_to_save_csv_file")
      val file: List[String] = dir
       .listFiles
       .filter(_.isFile)
       .filter(_.getName.endsWith(".csv"))
       .map(_.getName)
       .toList
```

After that I read each csv to a dataframe using a loop.

```
      for (fileName <- file){
        val df_fileName = spark
         .read
         .option("header", true)
         .csv("path_to_save_csv_file"+fileName)
         .toDF(classOf[caseClass_name].getDeclaredFields.map(x => x.getName):_*)
         .as[caseClass_name]
      }
```

In this way I can easily put my logic to each partition.

There should be an another better solution to solve this issue. As a beginner I put this answer according to my knowledge. I only post my answer to give an idea for who needs a help as me :)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I'll try it:)